# Rails: Best way to schedule emails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scheduled-tasks, actionmailer

Scenario: "I have 500 different types of posts (So emails are being sent various scheduled days exactly at 7 o'clock in the morning). A user signs up to receive 1 or more of those types of posts every day via email (keep in mind, this could mean 5,000+ emails per day)."

Looking around SO, I keep seeing the [`"Whenever" gem`](https://github.com/javan/whenever) come up as a solution but some are saying that it could cause spikes in the server. I also read some posts on [`delayed_job`](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) but some say that it freezes which I do not want to happen. I googled some more & still could not find anything close to being specific to my question.

What would be the best way to handle this, given my scenario & why?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use:

http://rubygems.org/gems/resque

in conjunction with:

https://rubygems.org/gems/resque_mailer

The best part is that you won't have to change the code, you just can send them like you did with ActionMailer!

Comment: Hey @Hallucynogenyc, thanks for your suggestion. I trying it out now. How heavy will this be on my server? My other main concern is the scheduling part. I'm looking at "resque-scheduler" but realize, my users will be selecting the date they'd like to receive the posts (deliver_at). Would these 3 gems (resque, resque_mailer, & resque_scheduler) suffice?

Comment: It will be as heavy as you want to. Scheduling gems won't load your server by themselves, but of course, if you ask them to send 100 mails at one point, of course it will load the server just as if you ran a task that sent the 100 mails. Either run this jobs on another server or send them in small batches. Because users are going to select when they want the mails, I wouldn't care much about server load.

Comment: Also, yes, those 3 gems should suffice.

Comment: Also, do you think "delayed_job" would be a better solution? (sorry if I'm being too inquisitive or obnoxious..)

Comment: I think both will do the job just fine, the difference being that the gems I suggested provide a mail-specific tool, while delayed-job is a general purpose solution. I would go for resque unless I had a problem with it.

Comment: Great. I'm playing around with "resque" atm, but still considering "delayed_job". Thanks again @Hallucynogenyc